# Amplitude.js + animatedModal.js

Tags: jquery

I am incorporating amplitude.js with animatedModal.js and just want to tweak it a bit to make everything work perfectly.  Currently, when I close the modal, the mp3 in amplitude continues to play.  I would like to make it pause the mp3 when I close the modal.

I think it can be done by using some of the tools already provided, but I am not sure how to call the functions correctly.

Here is the relevant portion of animatedModal.js where they have a callback created just for closing the modal:

```
function afterClose () {       
        id.css({'z-index':settings.zIndexOut,'left':settings.leftOut});
        settings.afterClose(); //afterClose
    }
```

Amplitude.js also provides a public function to pause the mp3:

```
        Amplitude.play()
```

Since amplitude is already initialized, I dont know the correct way to call that function in the afterclose function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. Either you add the following markup to the modal close button.

```
<span class="amplitude-pause"></span>
```

Or you need to have a function that fires the global pause button for amplitude.js. For example:

```
$('.close-button').on('click', function () {
   Amplitude.play()
});
```

Amplitude.play will pause whatever current song is playing.